# SQL Server Get Next Execution DateTime based on cron expression

Tags: sql-server, cron

I need help regarding Cron Expression in T-SQL. I want to make a T-SQL function taking two arguments:

1) Cron Expression

2) DateTime

And returns next execution DateTime after given one based on given Cron Expression.Something like code below

```
CREATE FUNCTION CronNextExecution(
@cronExpression NVARCHAR(100), 
@inputDate DATETIME)
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NextExecutionDateTime AS VARCHAR(50)
    --Some Algo to calculate Result
    RETURN @NextExecutionDateTime
END
GO
```

I am looking for any algo which I can convert to T-SQL or perhaps a T-SQL Script to calculate result.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need import your .dll into SQL Server. You can use NCronTab or any other library that do it's job.

Here is detailed instruction how to do this:

https://github.com/atifaziz/NCrontab/wiki/SQL-Server-Crontab

Otherwise, you would need to implement whole parsing and evaluating in T-SQL on your own.